# buildout can't find pip packages for Plone

Tags: python, pip, plone, buildout, egg

I'm trying to add add-ons to Plone through buildout but it can't find the packages. I've tried it in a virtualenv andd the system wide python

I followed the set up on the Plone site
[Setup instructions](https://docs.plone.org/manage/installing/installation.html)

Every add-on I try brings up the following error

```
Installing instance.
/home/a/Plone/zinstance/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:192: RuntimeWarning: You have iterated over the result of pkg_resources.parse_version. This is a legacy behavior which is inconsistent with the new version class introduced in setuptools 8.0. In most cases, conversion to a tuple is unnecessary. For comparison of versions, sort the Version instances directly. If you have another use case requiring the tuple, please file a bug with the setuptools project describing that need.
  stacklevel=1,
Couldn't find index page for 'collective.addthis' (maybe misspelled?)
Getting distribution for 'collective.addthis'.
Couldn't find index page for 'collective.addthis' (maybe misspelled?)
While:
  Installing instance.
  Getting distribution for 'collective.addthis'.
Error: Couldn't find a distribution for 'collective.addthis'.
```

I add the packages to the buildout.cnfg

```
eggs =
Plone
Pillow
collective.addthis
```

Plone and Pillow build fine but every add-on I try brings up the same error.

Answer (score 2):

there have been a lot of similar problems reported on https://community.plone.org/

the problem most probably is the migration from in pypi.python.org to pypi.org

you can add:

```
index = https://pypi.org/simple/
```

and if you are using allowed hosts you need 2 new ones and can skip *.python.org:

```
allow-hosts =
    pypi.org
    files.pythonhosted.org
```

alternatively you can use a current versions of setuptools and zc.buildout

attention: for setuptools > 38.7.0 you need to pin

```
plone.recipe.zope2instance = 4.4.0
```

(see https://github.com/plone/plone.recipe.zope2instance/blob/4.4.0/CHANGES.rst)

Comment: Thanks mate. Adding 'index = https://pypi.org/simple/'  fixed it for some of the packages but I now get the same error but for some of the package dependencies

Comment: I asked a new question since it's the dependencies that won't install now.. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221840/buildout-cant-find-the-links-for-the-dependecies-of-pypi-plone-add-ons]

Comment: FYI, https://community.plone.org is our official support forum, where you will get the most eyes on your questions