# Buildout can't find the links for the dependecies of Pypi Plone add-ons

Tags: python, pip, plone, pypi, buildout

I'm trying to install some add-ons to Plone but buildout can't find the links for the dependencies.

I have the following in my buildout.cnfg

```
find-links +=
http://dist.plone.org/release/5.0.4
http://getpaid.googlecode.com/files/yoma.batching-0.2.2-getpaid.zip
```

And

```
index = https://pypi.python.org/simple/
eggs =
    Plone
    Pillow
    collective.addthis
    collective.cart.shopping
    Products.PloneGetPaid
```

When I run

```
bin/buildout
```

I get

```
Getting distribution for 'plone.recipe.zope2instance==4.4.0'.
warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in distribution
Got plone.recipe.zope2instance 4.4.0.
Installing instance.
Couldn't find index page for 'getpaid.yoma.batching' (maybe misspelled?)
Getting distribution for 'getpaid.yoma.batching'.
Couldn't find index page for 'getpaid.yoma.batching' (maybe misspelled?)
While:
  Installing instance.
  Getting distribution for 'getpaid.yoma.batching'.
Error: Couldn't find a distribution for 'getpaid.yoma.batching'.
```

I followed the [Setup Guide](https://docs.plone.org/manage/installing/installation_minimal_buildout.html)
The only differences I made were to add `index = https://pypi.python.org/simple/`to the buildout.cnfg and to add `plone.recipe.zope2instance = 4.4.0` which didn't do anything and I added the [link](http://%20%20%20%20http://getpaid.googlecode.com/files/yoma.batching-0.2.2-getpaid.zip) to find-links which didn't do anything either

---

```
Plone
Pillow
collective.addthis
collective.cart.shopping
```

The first 3 install but before I added `index = https://pypi.python.org/simple/` only Plone and Pillow would install. The original error is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210505/buildout-cant-find-pip-packages-for-plone/51211212#51211212)

Answer (score 1):

getpaid.yoma.batching is not hosted on pypi.org.

try to search for it and you won't find any results:
https://pypi.org/search/?q=getpaid.yoma.batching

you can add it to your buildout as a development egg using mr.developer:

```
getpaid.yoma.batching               = git https://github.com/collective/getpaid.yoma.batching.git
```

or you can make a private release of the egg on a custom eggserver or apache/nginx with directory listing (using find-links)